# Protractor start with screen maximised firefox

Tags: angularjs, firefox, protractor, desiredcapabilities

I'm currently using the desired capability `--start-maximized` for chrome. Is there an equivalent option for firefox?

Thanks!

Comment: better to use some constant resolution

Comment: Thanks for your advice @Oleksii this helped :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I managed to solve it. I added to the onPrepare function in my protractor.conf.js the following,

```
(function() {browser.driver.manage().window().maximize();})();
```

This works for both firefox and chrome :)